# OpenShift hangs - cron jobs are not starting, have to ctrl+x when ssh'ing in

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

having a problem - i heavily depend on a daily cron job with RHC, and it randomly stops working from time to time.
Another symptom - when i log in with ssh, it prints the welcome prompt ("  !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!!") and then hangs - have to ctrl+x to actually see the prompt

I was suspecting script ran by a cronjob but there's nothing really special there, some DB communication and Amazon S3 upload, which should time out if something's wrong. Also, i'm echoing date into log first, then starting my script -- so if the script hangs, date should be there (or at least i think so) -- no date.

So - it looks pretty much like RHC stopping my gear when app is not in use -- but why the session is hang when i ssh ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like to me is that your application is being idled. If your a free user and your application hasn't received any external requests in 24 hours than your application will be idled. However as soon as it does receive a external request is will automatically start back up.

Sometimes when a gear is idled and you ssh into it the session can take a bit to put you to the command line. In other words you'll receive the IMPORTANT IMPORTANT text at the top but it might take a bit to actually get to the console.

Comment: that could explain it. I'll wait a bit longer next time when i see it. Thanks !

Comment: If its feasible, setup a external cronjob  to curl your OpenShift app every so often.